# Qt: How to track Release or Change event for Phonon::SeekSlider?

Tags: qt, phonon

I'm using Phonon::SeekSlider, it's a cool thing and I don't need to bother about synchronization between slider and MediaObject but now I need to track the moment when user releases the slider after moving it or when it's value is changed or when the current time of MediaObject is changed. I cannot find any public signals, I can see them in the slider's code but they are private. How could I inherit/implement/track whatever to track this event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class inherits SeekSlider
 
in the .h file :

```
#include <Phonon/SeekSlider>

using namespace Phonon;

class MySeekSlider : public SeekSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MySeekSlider(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void release(qint64 pos);
protected:
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *);
};
```

and in the.cpp

```
void MySeekSlider::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    emit release(this->pos());
}
```

or use the tick signal of your MediaObject

```
void    tick ( qint64 time )
```

Comment: I would try this approach too. I will do that tonight, cannot right now. Thanks

Comment: This approach works but improperly. I need this event would fired every time when you click, drag and then move slider but it's only fired when you click in some place in the slider.

Comment: I would try to write my own seek slider on the QSlider base, because this widget works correctly, so I need only to add some mediaObject functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You may connect to private signals same way as to any others. 
QStaticMetaObject ignores visibility level of signals|slots. The only difference of private signals from normal (which has protected visibility level) - you cannot emit them when subclassing your Phonon::SeekSlider.

Comment: I'm looking into the code of SeekSlider and cannot see any suitable private signals. The problem is SeekSlider doesn't inherit any slider, it's just a widget that has some slider as a part, and this slider itself is private and there is no access to it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no way to do it but to create a new class inherited from QSlider, and add the whole functionality about MediaObject inside.